# Rational Software Architect Methods and Attributes

Tags: uml, ibm-rad, ibm-rational, rational-rsa

I am using IBM Rational Software Architect to produce a class diagram.

When right clicking a diagram, choosing file, save as image.

Half of my attributes and methods, are inexplicably removed from the saved image.

Is there some setting causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately when using file -> save as image, result vary completely depending on the format chosen.

Jpeg and PNG will remove some methods, however GIF and BMP will not.

This is also true for sequence diagrams where message calls and labels will appear in different locations depending on image type.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a refresh problem. Try to go to the **class diagram contextual menu > Filter** and play around with the menu **show hide** attribute/method compartment.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the *Modeling->Pubish->Web...* feature as well.

It will give you a fully interactive HTML website, which includes the diagrams and model documentation. I'd be interested to see if the image it generates for your diagram has the same issue.